# ModX Evolution - display multiple resources on one page

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

I am trying to display multiple resources on one page in Evolution. Normally, I would use `getResources` in Revolution but this is not working for me this time round.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - in Evolution you can use [Ditto](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Ditto)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ditto in the same way as getResources but its just not as solid as getResources. Something like this.

```
[!Ditto?
    &parents=`12`
    &showInMenuOnly=`1`
    &orderBy=`menuindex ASC`
    &tpl=`sublayout-resource-to-pull-in`
!]
```